# Return multiple values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have these documents in my 'clash' collection

```
{
"firstname" : "Adam",
"lastname" : "Smith"
},
{
"firstame" : "John",
"lastname" : "Davis"
},
{
"firstame" : "Phoebe",
"lastname" : "Miller"
}
```

When I try to run the below query. I am able to get only one field using the map function.

```
db.clash.find({firstname:1, lastname:1}).toArray().map(function(result){ return result.firstname;})

[
"Adam",
"John",
"Phoebe"
]
```

I want my output to be something similar to this:

```
[                              {
"Adam",                         "Adam",  
"Smith"                         "Smith"
],                             },
[                              {  
"John",                         "John",
"Davis"           OR            "Smith"
],                             },
[                              {
"Phoebe",                       "Phoebe",
"Miller"                        "Miller"
]                              }
```

How do I get only the values of the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the map approach you're already using

```
db.clash.find({ ... }).toArray().map(function(result) {
  return [result.firstname, result.lastname];
});
```

This will get you something like

```
[
  [
    "Adam",
    "Smith"
  ],
  ...
]
```

You can also supply a second argument to [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) to make a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection).  This is usually the preferred method.

```
db.clash.find({ ... }, { _id: 0, firstname: 1, lastname: 1 }).toArray();
```

This will return something like

```
[
  {
    firstname: "Adam",
    lastname: "Smith"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for return [result.firstname, result.lastname];

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the field names and get only the values using the find() keyword?

Comment: If you want just the values you'd have to use something like `map` or `forEach` with `find()`.  You could also use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), but that may not be what you want